# Use constant vertical adjustment for text() and legend() regardless of plot dimensions

Tags: r

To draw X-axis labels for barplots in `R`, I use `text()` like this:

```
text(mean(bp), par("usr")[3] - 0.05*yDiff, xpd=NA, labels=journey, cex=0.9, font=2)
```

To draw a legend, I use something like this:

```
legend("bottom", legend=abbrevLabels, fill=c(colors), xpd=NA, horiz=TRUE, bty="n", 
   cex=1.0, inset=c(0, -0.3), xjust=0, adj=0.035, 
   text.width=rep(meanLabelLen/7.5, length(legendLabels)))
```

Both vertical offsets here -- the `0.05*yDiff` and the insert offset of `-0.3` for the legend -- are in Y-axis space.  For various reasons, that's a problem for me.  Instead, I prefer offsets in units of pixels.  That is, what I really want to say is: "render labels 10 pixels below the bottom of the graph".

How can this be done?

Comment: You should really make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we understand what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't.  Graph contents are proprietary.

Comment: Sure you can, in that case please consider [**How to make a great reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038). Show some effort! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For constant vertical offset of horizontal, X-axis labels situated underneath bar plots (at the bottom of a larger grid of such plots), it turns out that using `title` with the `line` attribute has consistent behavior / placement independent of device size.  Here is what I now do:

```
title(xlab=journey, line=0, cex=0.8, font.lab=2, xpd=NA)
```

where `line` is integral and `0` is nearest the plot, and a higher integer is further away (in the negative Y direction).

For the legend, I could not come up with a constant vertical offset that behaved independently of either grid dimensions or device size.  Several points here:

- `yjust` parameter to `legend` *did not* work at all.  I looked online for examples, but no matter what value I used, `yjust` was a no-go.
- `y` parameter *does* work, but regrettably, *not* in conjunction with a descriptive attribute for `x`; that is, if `x` is set to `bottom`, you cannot concurrently set `y`.  I found this behavior disconcerting, as I would generally expect these coordinates to be independent of each other.

To work around these limitations, here is what I did:

```
yInset <- 0.4 * (1.075 - par("fin")[2] / dev.size("in")[2])
legend(x='bottom', yjust=-0.75, inset=c(0, -yInset), legend=abbrevLabels, fill=c(colors), xpd=NA, horiz=TRUE, bty="n", cex=1.0, adj=0.035, text.width=rep(meanLabelLen/7.5, length(legendLabels)))
```

This logic effectively sets up a sliding Y-offset in proportion to grid dimensions and device size.  The empirically determined scaling / offset factors of `1.075` and `0.4` are truly gross, but for now suffice.

It would help in the future if some of the limitations for `legend` cited above are resolved (or possibly better explained in the case that I misunderstood the docs).